# Set RadioMenuItem value

Tags: java, fxml

I have the following FXML:

```
<fx:define><ToggleGroup fx:id="toggleGroup"/></fx:define>
<Menu text="gender" onAction="#handleChange">
  <RadioMenuItem text="%male" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup"/>
  <RadioMenuItem text="%female" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup"/>
</Menu>
```

Is there a way to set a value on a RadioMenuItem?

I want to use something like the following:

```
@FXML public void handleChange(ActionEvent e) {
  RadioMenuItem selectedItem = (RadioMenuItem)event.getTarget();
  // here I need a value from a RadioMenuItem
  // Male or female? (language dependent)
}
```

Since text is language dependent I can't use it. Is there an other property on RadioMenuItem that I can access? `fx:id` is not the way. Maybe `fx:value` or `fx:constant`?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! There is a `userData` attribute.

Code would be

```
<fx:define><ToggleGroup fx:id="toggleGroup"/></fx:define>
<Menu text="gender" onAction="#handleChange">
  <RadioMenuItem text="%male" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup" userData="m"/>
  <RadioMenuItem text="%female" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup" userData="f"/>
</Menu>
```

Then you can use it like

```
@FXML public void handleChange(ActionEvent e) {
  RadioMenuItem selectedItem = (RadioMenuItem)event.getTarget();

  String value = (String)selectedItem.getUserData(); // This returns the data as Object.
}
```